# c++ how to push a single element of vector<bitset> into a queue or list

Tags: c++, list, vector, queue

```
//256 lines
00000000 0000000
00000001 1000000
00000010 0000010
................
................
```

I put the

**1st column** --> `std::vector<std::bitset<8> > a`

**2nd column** --> `std::vector<std::bitset<8> > b`

I want to compare elements of these vectors and push a single element from any vector into a list or a queue. I want to know how to push a single element of a vector into a queue or list and display it.

I have seen example with vector into a queue but how to push the above vector element into it.

ex:

`00000000 == 00000000` leave it

`00000001 != 10000000` push `00000001` into the queue or list.

I have written the code till reading the lines in file into vector and compare the vectors.I want to know how to push a single element of a vector into a queue or list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

void pvb(std::vector<std::bitset<8> > v)
{
for(int x=0;x<v.size();++x)
{
    for(int y=7;y>=0;--y)
    {
        std::cout << v[x][y];

    }
    std::cout << '\n';
   }
}

 int main()
 {
   std::vector<std::bitset<8> > a2d,b2d;

   std::ifstream in("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/hwb8_64.pla");
   std::string Line;

   if(!in) //Always test the file open.
   {
    cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
   }

  while(!in.eof())
  {
     std::getline(in,Line);
     if( Line[0] != '#')   //skip lines starting with '.'
     {
        if(Line[0] !='.')
        {
           if(Line == " ")
           {
              std::cout<<"end of the file\n";
              break;
           }
          //vector(bitset)
          istringstream is(Line);
          std::string b1,b2;
          while(is >> b1 >> b2)
          {
            std::bitset<8> x(b1);
            std::bitset<8> y(b2);
            a2d.push_back(x);
            b2d.push_back(y);
          }  
        }
     }
   }

 // display the inputs and outputs
 std::cout << "inputs\n";
 pvb(a2d);
 system("PAUSE");
 std::cout << "outputs\n";
 pvb(b2d);
 system("PAUSE");

 //compare the vectors
 for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
 {
  if(a[i] == b[i]){
  std::cout<< "a==b";
  }
  else{
  // push a[i] into queue or list 
  // push b[i] into queue or list
  } 
  return 0;
  }
```

I have seen many examples regarding this topic but I couldn't make out on to how to store a single element from vector into a queue or list.

Comment: "push [..] into a list or a queue" - your code doesn't contain any of these.

Comment: I don't understand the need for nested `std::vector` don't suffice with `std::vector<std::bitset<8>>` for `a3d` and `b3d`.

Comment: I want to know how to push only `00000001` in `vector a` to a queue and not the entire vector.